# Should I delete my question? Whats wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently posted a question about numbers. I was thinking that it was a legitimate question. Maybe I didn't ask it well, but I saw similar questions (such as [Does Pi contain all possible number combinations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations)). My question is:

[Is there a number so large that we could never calculate it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367458/is-there-a-number-so-large-that-we-could-never-caculate-it)

I wasn't sure if there was an answer or if there is any information or if anyone even asked this question before… But I was really curious about it. Now I regret asking because I feel most of the people think my thoughts are just stupid (someone even referred to some program for children), but I like a couple of the links I was given.

Is there something wrong with my question? Should I delete it?

Comment: Personally I don't think there is anything wrong with the question. I can answer it, I think. I've voted to reopen and I hope at least four others will do as well.

Comment: I think the question should be re-opened. For now, I've posted an answer there as a pair of comments. My answer presumes that you want not only to calculate a number, but that you also want to *know* that you've calculated it -- i.e., a computation together with a proof of correctness.

Comment: Speaking only for myself, I think it's a perfectly valid question for a math Q & A place like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having looked at your question, I think that some of the commentary was a bit harsh (luckily I can fix that). I also felt that the chosen close reason (chosen by four of the five close-voters) wasn't appropriate. Were I to have voted, I would have chosen **unclear what you're asking** because, well, it's unclear exactly what you are asking. (The fifth close-voter chose this option.)

Your main question is

> are there numbers that are just too large ... that we can't write them down in any way at all that expresses their exact value?

This leaves a lot to be interpreted. What do you mean by "write them down in any way"? And how should one writing "express their exact value"? I would assume that a number's decimal representation expresses their exact value. But what about the following?

> $\operatorname{TREE}(3)$ where $\operatorname{TREE}(k)$ is the maximal length of a sequence $T_1 , \ldots , T_\ell$ of $k$-labelled trees where $T_i$ has at most $i$ vertices, and no labelled tree embeds as a minor (together with its labeling) into a later labelled tree in the sequence. (See the [Googology Wiki](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/TREE_sequence).)

This gives a definition of a unique number, but really doesn't help in determining much about the number. (Well, it does make [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) look like an infinitesimal, but that's not exactly immediate.) Would this be a way to write down a number in a way that expresses its exact value?

What you mean by these really affects what the question is, and what suitable answers are. There might be an interesting semi-philosophical question here, but as it stands I'm not certain it can be appropriately answered (hence, I feel it is unclear).

If you don't feel that you can make it more clear, then deletion is an option, although if it doesn't get re-opened it will likely be a candidate for [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006).

Comment: Completely off-topic, but I don't understand why $T_1$ (the tree with one vertex) would not embed in the following trees...

Comment: @Najib The embedding has to respect the labeling. So, in particular, whatever label the unique vertex in $T_1$ is given, no other vertex in any later tree can be given that label.

Comment: Thank you very much for your full response. I'm not always good at expressing the questions I have, but I didn't realize it was _that_ ambiguous. I tried to at least make it somewhat specific so that I wouldn't get an answer like "Let x be a number. Let x go to infinity" or something like that. It is difficult to explain my thoughts here. Other than a "trick" like the limit I gave, I feel like there must be numbers that are simply too big to ever calculate or express. I'm not sure how else to ask this and I'm considering closing the question.